# Get order id after purchase completed

Tags: orders, payment, purchase-order

I need to get order id after payment is successfully completed. Is there observer to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `sales_order_payment_pay` event to get the order id after payment is completed successfully.

below code in **etc/config.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <global>
        <events>
            <sales_order_payment_pay>
                <observers>
                    <Namespace_Module>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>Namespace_Module/Observer</class>
                        <method>getOrder</method>
                    </Namespace_Module>
                </observers>
            </sales_order_payment_pay>     
        </events>
     </global>
</config>
```

and **Model/Observer.php**

```
public function getOrder($observer) {
    $orderId = $observer->getPayment()->getOrder()->getId();
    $orderNumber = $observer->getPayment()->getOrder()->getIncrementId();
}
```

Just to clarify; The order ID is used internally in the database. The order number is what's displayed on screen and looks like `#100000153`

Answer (score 3):

Yes there are few events related to payment.

I would suggest to use this one: `sales_order_payment_pay`.

[Complete events](https://www.nicksays.co.uk/magento-events-cheat-sheet-1-9/)

I believe you already know how to use observer.

Comment: You are welcome.